# Entity Framework Include without query

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Can I include a related object without a query?

With query:

```
Item item = _db.Items
               .Include(i=>i.Supplier)
               .Where(....)
```

Without query:

```
var item = new Item { Name = "Test", SupplierId = 1 };
item.Include(i => i.Supplier); //something like that...
```

Comment: Have you mapped the suppliers relationship? Have you profiled the SQL being generated?

Comment: Do you want attach object to the context? See [Add/Attach](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592676.aspx). `Include` method designed for [eager loading](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand your question...

First of all **Where** return multiple objects

```
IQueryable<Item> items = _db.Items
               .Include(i=>i.Supplier)
               .Where(....)
```

Then the result is an **IQueryable**, the items and suppliers objects are not materialized for the moment. You have to use **ToList()** for example to enable materialization and query the database.

For the **Include** method, it's just a *join* to query Items and Suppliers relationship.
But the **Include** extension method is only available in IQueryable and not for the entity.

Supplier is normal a simple navigation property on item entity

```
class Item
{
public virtual Supplier Supplier {get; set;}
}
```

so you can access using

```
var item = new Item { Name = "Test", SupplierId = 1 };
item.Supplier = ....
```

if you want establish a relation with you have to get the supplier

```
item.Supplier = _db.Suppliers.First(s => s.SupplierId = 1);
```